# Open image dialog/GridView is very slow

Tags: android, gridview

**What I have**

I have an "open image dialog" in an activity. This "dialog" only shows folders and compatible images. For this I have a layer with a gridview that I fill with rows that contains an image and a text.

The text is for the name of the file and the image is for a preview of the image.

**My problem**

The dialog works well if the folder that I'm seeing doesn't have lots of images. I'm working on a SII and when I try to open the camera album (photos of 8Mpx) it goes very slow with my code, even each time a new row is redrawed.

**My code**

I think the main problem resides in the creation of the preview images because if I delete this part all works fine. For the images, I have:

```
  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View grid;

   if(convertView==null){
       grid = new View(mContext);
       LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
       grid=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
   }else{
       grid = (View)convertView;
   }

   ImageView icon = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.file_image);
   TextView label = (TextView)grid.findViewById(R.id.file_text);
   label.setText(item.get(position));
    if (item.get(position).equals("/")){
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.folderupup);
    }else if (item.get(position).endsWith("../")) {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.folderup);
    }else if (item.get(position).endsWith("/")) {    
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.folder);
    }else{
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path.get(position));
        Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 55, 55, false);
        icon.setImageBitmap(b2);
    }

   return grid;
  }
 }
```

Comment: You might want to consider using a background thread doing image loading. Here is a great tutorial of how to do so: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html

Comment: Another tip: ViewHolder pattern is very useful for gridview and listview. Here is an article that shows how to use ViewHolder pattern: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html

Comment: I have added ViewHolder and now I'm trying to add background thread. I have added the code you give me but, what's the var "mPlaceHolderBitmap"? I don't know what it is and I have an error there.

Comment: Forget to mention, there is a blue button says "Download the sample" on the upper right corner in this page http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html, where you can download the complete source code, and they are under Apache License. If I remember correctly, there are classes that you will need: ImageWorker, ImageResizer, and AsyncTask. Take these classes and replace the cache mechanism with in memory cache using SoftReference. This is going to be a really good learning experience.

Comment: Yesterday I tried but I couldn't archive anything with the zip. Because I thougth the zip was more complete I tried to do something with it today and finally I archive it! I have copied most of all project and correct the methods so I can get them from files and not from net but altough the list goes softly the images load very slowly. I think it's because a method, can you check it in my next message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did all that the Android page said without doing anything for the cache. Now the list loads fast. Maybe I could add a memory cache as Wenhui pointed but it is so fast that it doesn't matter for my purposes.

The test has been done on a SII with a folder containing around 400 with 8Mpx

Answer (score 0):

In somewhere, the code calls this (data is the full pathname of the image):

```
DiskLruCache.Editor editor = mHttpDiskCache.edit(key);
if (editor != null) {
       if (downloadUrlToStream(data,editor.newOutputStream(DISK_CACHE_INDEX))) {
             editor.commit();
       } else {
             editor.abort();
       }
}
```

because I don't know how to change it, I modified the url receptor so now instead of reading from the net it reads from a file:

```
    public boolean downloadUrlToStream(String urlString, OutputStream outputStream) {
        disableConnectionReuseIfNecessary();
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedOutputStream out = null;
        BufferedInputStream in = null;

        try {

            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(urlString)), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

            int b;
            while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(b);
            }
            return true;
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in downloadBitmap - " + e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (final IOException e) {}
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But the gridview load the images very slowly. I think it's because the last method. How can I do it better?

Comment: Where do you get the image from? From Http, file or resources?

Comment: files. It's for an open dialog. I need to show the structure of folders and then the thumbnails of the images files. I have thought that maybe I could use the cache that android has made for exploring the folders so I would only create a cache image for those files that Android hasn't do it yet. The problem is that the name of the files created with android cache is different from the name of my cache and I don't know how they have done it.

Comment: Don't know anything about the android cache, but you can get the image from files and scale it down and then display it. The method above is not used for file. There is method for file, `decodeSampledBitmapFromFile` from ImageResizer, and you probably don't need to use DiskLruCache, use something like HashMap with SoftReference to cache your thumbnails.

Comment: yes I'm using this method. I will try what you say. I didn't try it because google help says that is not a good idea to use SoftReference since they did Android 3.0 because the garbage collector is more agressive with this method