# android error while using dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am implementing a dialog fragment which should open when i click on an item in a gridview of images. here is my code

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(position==0)
            {
                    FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();

ImageDial1 id1=new ImageDial1();
                ImageDial1.show(fm,"image_title");
```

and the dialog fragment code is this

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ImageDial1 extends DialogFragment {
    public ImageDial1() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagefrag1, container, false);
      }


}
```

I am getting an error "cannot make a static reference to non static method show()" in this line

```
ImageDial1.show(fm,"image_title");
```

Where am i going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change here

> ImageDial1.show(fm,"image_title");

to

> id1.show(fm,"image_title");

Comment: one more thing, when i try to open an enlarged image in the dialog of the thumbnail in the gridview, the transition is very slow and lags. How can i make it smoother?

Comment: m sry i have no idea..
check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789939/open-image-dialog-gridview-is-very-slow